# Is ByVal a lie?

Tags: excel, vba, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I think I've recently (finally) started to get to grips with how `ByVal` and `ByRef` work in VBA.

#### Observations

In all the tutorials and references I've been through to date, `ByRef` was always "passing the object", `ByVal` was "passing a copy of the object". To me the latter meant the object's place in memory was duplicated and a pointer to that new location was returned. I now realise that's not always the case, in fact as far as I can tell it's rarely the case: instead, most objects and classes are in fact passed `ByRef` even with `ByVal` specified in a routine's signature.

A `System.Collections.ArrayList` is passed silently ByRef as demonstrated in this code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim list1 As Object, list2 As Object
    Set list1 = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    list1.Add "foo"
    Set list2 = RemoveItem(list1)
    Debug.Assert list2.Contains("foo") = False 'as expected
    Debug.Assert list1.Contains("foo") = True  'raises error, meaning list1 was passed byref not byval
End Sub

Function RemoveItem(ByVal list As Object) As Object 'ByVal
    list.Remove "foo" 'expect to remove from a copy and return that
    Set RemoveItem = list
End Function
```

That surprised me given what I thought I knew about `ByVal`. Further digging shows me that to get a copy like I want from `ByVal` I need the objects I'm passing to have a method that enables this. For an `ArrayList`, the `.Clone` method makes a *shallow copy*. So my function becomes:

```
Function RemoveItem(ByRef list As Object) As Object 'ByRef or ByVal, makes no difference
    Dim listCopy As Object
    Set listCopy = list.Clone 'make a shallow copy of the object
    listCopy.Remove "foo" 'actually remove from a copy and return that
    Set RemoveItem = listCopy
End Function
```

A VB `Array` raises a compiler error when passed ByVal, perhaps as a warning against just this

#### Questions

All that got me thinking:

1. What is the difference (if any) between `ByVal` and `ByRef` for classes/objects
2. What distinguishes certain types (`Boolean`, `Long`) which can be passed `ByVal` from classes and types that can't
3. In terms of library references - things that may not be written in `VB6`

   - Is it possible to create an object with a default `ByVal` response?

     - In Python you can specify how a class reacts to different keywords. I doubt you can do that natively in VBA, but could an object written in a more versatile language ever say, detect if it is being passed `ByVal` and return a `.Clone` of itself.
     - In other words, how do VBA's built-in datatypes get passed `ByVal` and can any other objects mimic this behaviour (again, in Python, everything's an object so everything's behaviour can be copied*). Or do I not have to worry about this ever happening?
   - Is it possible to mimic an `Array`'s behaviour and raise a compiler error when passed `ByVal` - as an array has no clone method and cannot be readily copied so is always `ByRef`
4. Is there a Sub, Function or method that will let me create *deep-copies* of objects? That is, a generic way of duplicating the memory one object uses, and creating a second copy of an object.

**anecdotal, I'm very new to Python*

Comment: Maybe [this](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-sub/#ByRef_and_ByVal_with_Objects) is of help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In all the tutorials and references I've been through to date, ByRef was always "passing the object", ByVal was "passing a copy of the object".

Do you have a link for an example of the above?

1. For objects (created from classes) `ByVal` is like `*foo` whilst `ByRef` is like `**foo`.
2. Boolean and Long are primitives, for primitives `ByVal` is like `bar`  whilst `ByRef` is like `*bar`.
3. - no

     - there is no way for a object to tell if it has been passed `ByRef` or `ByVal`.
     - VBA 'built-in' datatypes have analogues in C/C++ so `Long` is a 32-bit integer so is `Boolean` in fact but can only take one of two values (0=False,-1=True).  You need not worry, VBA places limits in the name of safety.
   - If you want to enforce passing `ByRef` for your objects then create a Type instead of a class.
4. For classes, you will have to write your own copy constructors both shallow and deep.  But Types can be copied just by using `=`  both shallow and deep.

Arrays and Types are passed `ByRef` because they are created on the stack.

Comment: What does ByVal is like *foo whilst ByRef is like **foo mean please?

Comment: @QHarr: Interface Definition Langauge (IDL) (based on  C++) terminology, where asterisk * means a pointer to.

Comment: @QHarr: I recommend OLEView, it shows all the interfaces in IDL, http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2017/04/throw-away-declare-function-with-idl.html

Answer (score 1):

For objects and classes in VBA there is no real difference in passing byval or byref. Passing byref ony means the pointer is passed 'byref', the object remains the same.

If you think of it, it make sense for (Excel) objects; whether you pass 
Range("A1") byref or byval, it is still the same cell we're addressing.

Comment: Sir, I beg to differ.  If SubA has a variable objFoo and calls SubB passing objFoo ByRef then SubB can change what objFoo points to.  I.e. SubB can change the contents of a variable in SubA's scope. That is not possible with ByVal.  So I'm saying SubB can corrupt SubA's variables if you use ByRef.

Comment: You're right, I thought of that last night, away from my computer :-)